# Adding url to woocommerce cart

Tags: woocommerce

[can you help me how this field is made.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO97R.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need new custom field on the checkout page. So, you can use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-regsiter-field-editor/

Also, you can add this field manually:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field ($checkout ) {
   echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field">';
   woocommerce_form_field('customised_field_name', array(
     'type' => 'text',
     'class' => array( 'my-field-class form-row-wide' ),
     'label' => __('Customise Additional Field'),
     'placeholder' => __('Guidence'),
     'required' => true,
   ), $checkout->get_value('customised_field_name'));
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Ofcourse, you need to modify this code for yourself, for example you can change action point from 'woocommerce_before_order_notes' to some other to move the field.

Comment: The add-on only works in the billing department.
I need to arrange the cart area.